# Firefox driver bot recognition

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to make a program with a selenium Webdriver in python. I use a proxy and with the Firefox driver. But it get recognized as a bot by google (I get the warning 'Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network') and I need to solve a captcha. This does not happen with the Chrome driver, because there I solved it with through this site:
[Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)
. I changed the window.navigator.webdriver, but I still get recognized as a bot. The weird thing is that I don't get recognized as a bot without a proxy. What can I do with this? Thanks in advance, any idea will be great

Comment: Is it a shared proxy? That happens when google gets suspicious traffic from an ip address. @DebanjanB - this is a different issue than your link.

Comment: Yeah it is a shared proxy, but I don't get the warning with chrome or safari.

Comment: @pguardiario Reopened.

Comment: You can't scrape google with shared proxies because other people are burning the ip address.

Comment: Oke, but can you explain why I don't get the warning with safari?